# How to make Eclipse plugin web browser automatically resize web pages to fit the view size?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, browser

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin, and it has a web browser view. Since the view is quite small, each time the browser gets a web page to show, it only shows a little part of it.
What can I do to resize web pages to make them fit the size of my browser view? Or are there open source web browsers that have already implemented this that I can use?

Comment: Do you mean scaling the whole page to fit? Web sites often adjust to fit the width of the view.

Comment: yes, I think now web sites often do that, but I didn't see it, don't know what to do

Comment: Wikipedia certainly adjusts to the width for me using the normal SWT Browser control. Other sites may not be so flexible.

Comment: I think you are right, and I think maybe I can do things like the resizing function(Ctrl + mouse) most web browsers provide, do you know how this function is implemented?

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about this. The SWT Browser control is just a thin wrapper around the native browser.